# Is it possible to override minikube IP and hostname when it runs in driver=none mode without performing minkube delete?

Tags: azure, centos, minikube

Scenario: minikube gets installed on an Azure VM with CentOS in driver=none mode and with metallb and some other things installed on top of it, VM then get's snapshotted and reprovisioned with different IP and hostname. Once it had been reprovisioned minikube is up yet it keeps reusing "old" IP and hostname.

My goal is to snapshot VM with configured minikube and then spin off new VMs (= VM IP & hostname change) so that minikube can work without performingg minkikube delete (I'm OK with restarts and adjusting config files either via minikube start switches or through init scripts)

Is there a way to change IP/hostname without performing minkube delete?  What about changing hostname?

It looks like *--static-ip* switch available in more recent versions of minikube wont't be helpful here as it is only supported with Docker or Podman driver.